# Limit mongoose schema type to string enum

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema:

```
const roles = {
    USER: 'user',
    OWNER: 'owner',
    ADMIN: 'admin'
};


let userSchema = Schema({
           role:
            {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                default: roles.USER
            },
});
```

I want to limit the type of "role" to only strings from the "roles" object. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add to your schema `enum: Object.values(roles)`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using a Enum in Mongoose is what you are looking for

```
export enum Roles {
  ADMIN = 'admin',
  USER = 'user',
  OWNER = 'owner',
};

let userSchema = Schema({
       role:
       {
           type: String,
           enum : Roles,
           required: true,
           default: Roles.USER
       },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! "enum" seems to do exactly that.